# Symbol for relative entropy

Tags: symbols

Could you help me with typesetting the following symbol (marked by red frame):

[image]

I searched over all possible manuals but was not able to find it. It looks like capital D, but actually it is not the same.

Comment: Do you have a pdf source of this picture? Then we can at least identify the font.

Comment: No, unfortunately I do not have a pdf. It is from the book "probabilistic graphical models" by Daphne Koller and Nir Friedman, [page 42](http://books.google.kg/books?id=7dzpHCHzNQ4C&pg=PA42&lpg=PA42&dq=probabilistic+graphical+models+consider+a+sequence+of+N+independent+samples+from+a+binary&source=bl&ots=pu4CAp6ZrR&sig=TFmJZeHXIy6Fng-zKIgpx1HhJjo&hl=en&sa=X&ei=DK1DUbWaLIGhqgGb0IDwAg&ved=0CDEQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=probabilistic%20graphical%20models%20consider%20a%20sequence%20of%20N%20independent%20samples%20from%20a%20binary&f=false)

Comment: Could `$\mathbb{D}$` be a valid approximation?

Comment: For me \mathbb{D} gives a different symbol with a double frame.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It looks to me like a constructed symbol (and even if it is a font, it may be easier to construct the symbol than find the font). For example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}


\begin{document}


$I\mkern-8muD((p,1-p)$

\end{document}
```